# React-native get method return value

Tags: javascript, react-native, methods, return-value

I have the following method in my class MakeRequest.js:

```
export default class MakeRequest{
    send() {
        var data = 'foo';
        var data2 = 'bar';
        return [data, data2];
    }
}
```

I am trying to access data and data2 from a different class:

```
(array) => MakeRequest.send(JSON.stringify(query));
alert(array[0]);
```

The error message displayed is

```
Can't find variable: array
```

Why is 'array' not accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is out of scope. Your lambda ends with the `send` call. If you're wanting to alert within it, and not return the output of that method call, do something like this:

```
(array) => {
    MakeRequest.send(JSON.stringify(query));
    alert(array[0]);
}
```